# How to repeat JUnit5 tests on class level?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm using JUnit5 for the integration tests, where I have a use-case for repeating tests within the class, but I'd like to preserve the original order of tests. Is there a way with JUnit5 to achieve this?

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class TestExample {
    final int nrOfIterations = 3;

    @Order(1)
    @DisplayName("One")
    @RepeatedTest(value = nrOfIterations, name = RepeatedTest.LONG_DISPLAY_NAME)
    void repeatedTestWithRepetitionInfo(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) {
        System.out.println("One #" + (repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition()-1));
        assertEquals(3, repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions());
    }

    @Order(2)
    @DisplayName("Two")
    @RepeatedTest(value = nrOfIterations, name = RepeatedTest.LONG_DISPLAY_NAME)
    void repeatedTestWithRepetitionInfoCont(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) {
        System.out.println("two #" + (repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition()-1));
        assertEquals(3, repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
One #0
One #1
One #2
two #0
two #1
two #2
```

And I want to get:

```
One #0
two #0
One #1
two #1
One #2
two #2
```

Comment: Tests must not depend on the execution order!

Comment: I disagree, unit test "should" not, but those are integration tests and with JUnit5, it is not just unit-testing platform anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I was thinking about the following solution:

```
class RepeatTest {
    final int nrOfIterations = 3;

    void test1(int runNr) {
        System.out.println("One #" + runNr);
    }

    void test2(int runNr) {
        System.out.println("Two #" + runNr);
    }

    @RepeatedTest(value = nrOfIterations)
    @TestFactory
    Stream<DynamicNode> factory(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) {
        final int runNr = repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition() - 1;
        return Stream.of(
                DynamicTest.dynamicTest("One", () -> test1(runNr)),
                DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Two", () -> test2(runNr))
        );
    }    
}
```

but due to the limitation in JUnit 5 it does not work:

[Test methods cannot combine RepeatedTest and ParameterizedTest annotations](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1224)

The best way I can think about to reach your goal is less elegant, but is still does what you expect:

```
@RepeatedTest(value = nrOfIterations)
void repeatedTestWithRepetitionInfo(RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) {
    final int runNr = repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition() - 1;
    test1(runNr);
    test2(runNr);
    assertEquals(3, repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions());
}
```

The disadvantage is that only each complete repetition is displayed as a single test run, and not each individual tests as you requested.

I am aware that this does not *fully* answer your question and I'd rather post it as a comment, but I would not have the required formatting capabilities and text length; and above all my solution at least *partially* does what you requested :)

Comment: I did not wanted to have everything clogged up in one test, but looks like this is my only option so far. Hopefully eventually your first solution will be supported. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because probably there is nothing better out there as of now.

Comment: @user52028778 I am not happy either that there is not a better answer :(